# Converting phpdoc to docset usable by Dash

Tags: php, documentation, documentation-generation, docset

I'm trying to get the [Magento Documentation](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/) in a format which I can use in [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash/). An [article](http://kapeli.com/docsets/) on the Dash website describes how to import a number of types of documentation into the required format, unfortunately phpdoc is not one of them.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm the developer behind Dash. Currently there is no phpdoc to docset generation script, so you're stuck with creating one yourself I'm afraid.

However, I do recommend taking the easy way out, which is generating the docset based on the PHP source using doxygen (see "Creating Docsets using Doxygen" inside the [article](http://kapeli.com/docsets/) you linked). If you need help, feel free to [contact me](http://kapeli.com/contact).